# What does [::] mean as an ip address? Bracket colon colon bracket

Tags: ip, ipv6

When I run netstat there are some entries such as `TCP  [::]:8010  computername LISTENING`

What does that mean? It is impossible to search for...

Comment: My knowledge is not up to giving a proper answer, but I do recognise it as IPv6.

Comment: Oh so I guess it is the equivalent of 0.0.0.0 in IPv6?

Comment: Yep, that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`::` can be used once in an IPv6 address to replace a consecutive blocks of zeroes. It can be any length of zeroes as long as it is greater than a single block. All zeroes in a single block can be represented by `:0:` instead of writing out all four zeroes.

In this case, it means all zeroes, or the IPv6 equivalent of the IPv4 `0.0.0.0`

---

As an example of something that is *not* all zeroes:

`fe80:0000:0000:0000:34cb:9850:4868:9d2c`

Which is properly "reduced" to:

`fe80::34cb:9850:4868:9d2c`

As an example, it can also be written as:

`fe80:0:0:0:34cb:9850:4868:9d2c`

but that is far less common than just "double coloning" it.

Comment: Can you give an example of a v6 address that isn't all zeros

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6#Address_format

Comment: You didn't expand the actual IP address OP asked for, mention that the "all zeros" IP address is the "unspecified address" for when IP is unknown, nor explain the square brackets delimit the IP address from the port number. Please update your answer.

Comment: Non-zero blocks can be abbreviated as well by removing the leading zeros for that block.  For example: 0000:00ff:0099:0101:0000:0200:0000:0000 can be abbreviated as 0:ff:99:101:0:200::

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/ipv6-overview-24/index.html writes "You can use the two colon notation to replace any contiguous fields of all zeros in the IPv6 address.", and the last example replaces only a single block. Does that contradict what you say in "... as long as it is greater than a single block"?

Answer (score 30):

:: is the IPv6 "unspecified" address, equivalent to 0.0.0.0 - the [] is notation to separate the address from the port specifier.

A program bound to :: will be given traffic for any actual IPv6 address assigned to the system - it may also receive IPv4 traffic too in the form of IPv6-mapped IPv4 addresses (::ffff:x.x.x.x) although this is dependent on the socket options set by the application.

Comment: Sources: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.2 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4

Answer (score 1):

This issue and diagram is helpful for understanding the "big picture":

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9390#issuecomment-278001837